# How to check the readyState of a document created with createHTMLDocument()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to check the `readyState` of a document created with `createHTMLDocument()` as it is loading, but as far as I can tell the document is (and is supposed to be) returned immediately and fully-loaded. For example, the code below prints "complete" to the console, so the loading is complete as soon as the doc is assigned to the variable:

```
function makeDocument() {
  var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Doc");
  console.log(doc.readyState);
}
```

I feel like I should be able to attach something to `doc`'s `onreadystatechange` property, but the document needs to exist before I can do that. Any suggestions?

By the way, I'm not trying to do this in service of anything else, I just would like to know if it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the document ready upon creation?

Comment: Yes, but does it go through the loading and interactive states?

Comment: I guess not, why should it? It's not loaded into a browser window only in memory.

Comment: You're probably right.

Comment: Because I'm not confused enough, `DOMParser().parseFromString()` returns an uninitialized document.